# Перегрев ЦП Intel i7 4770K

Tags: cpu, intel

Знаю что ЦП перегревается, решил посмотреть температуры и тут такое:

AIDA64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HWMonitor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SpeedFan

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кому верить и вообще сильный ли перегрев, нагрузку показывает 90-100% (Рендер видео)

Comment: Разве программы по контролю железа не имеют отношения к системному администрированию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приветствую.

Для измерения температуры процессора лучше воспользоваться пакетом программ, который входит в комплекте с материнской платой. Обычно там есть мониторинг частоты CPU и его температуры.

У меня процессор i7 3820. При запуске без кулера он выключался, не доходя до 75 градусов.

Согласно [спецификации](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/75123/Intel-Core-i7-4770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) максимальная температура работы для i7 4770K - 72.72°C

Comment: Спасибо за совет, так и сделаю! То есть он должен просто вырубать комп при прохождении порога 72.72 градусов?

Comment: Если неразогнанный то да

Comment: Но лучше до такого не доводить

Comment: Понятно, не понимаю тогда смысла во всех этих программах, если они дают ложные показания датчиков. Сравню с прогой от материнки.

Comment: На каком то железе дают точные показания, на каком то нет